# ending script after file already exists

Tags: bash, shell-script

`test -f "$name" || touch "$name"`

So I use this command to test if the file already exists but the problem now is if the file is a copy, my script continue in the same file, while I just want the script to end after it already exists with the text `"this file already exists"` end script.

Comment: What you mean "file is a copy"? Has a different name?

Comment: no i mean if the file already exists by name i want my script to end, because now it continue in that same file that already exists.

Comment: Ok.. So you just need help to perform `if-then-else` if file exists, like this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170677/shell-script-check-if-file-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With simple condition:

```
if test -f "$name"; then 
    echo "this file already exists"
    exit 1
else 
    touch "$name"
fi
```